# iOS 6 File Type Association Issues

Tags: email, mime-types, attachment

I'm having the same problem as mentioned [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4489540?start=0&tstart=0).
When trying to open `.dwg` files from email attachment, my application appears in the list of available applications, but IOS 6 devices - iPad only - fail to open the application.

Error:

```
LaunchServices: Invalid LSOpenOperation request - No applications found to open document
```

I've tried different `public.mime-type` values, with no success.
How can I know the correct `mime-type`? Is there any other solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance!